# MongoDB duplicate value under same collection but different sub collection

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    col1:{
        key1: "val1"
    },
    col2: {
        key1: "val1"            
    }        
}
```

If I have these 2 small collections within the large collection, how does it work to be **allowed** to have "val1" in col1 and col2, but not:

```
{
    col1:{
        key1: "val1",
        key2: "val1"
    },
    col2: {
        key1: "val1"
        key2: "val1"
    }        
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by collection here? You are showing documents.!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first of all Collection has a specific meaning in context of MongoDB. collection means (sort of) table and document means (sort of) row. Please refer the nomenclature of MongoDB otherwise question makes and will make little to no sense.

Here I guess you are talking about structure in a single collection where document is not allowing to have a duplicate value.

MongoDB is really flexible so it would allow you to store duplicate values **unless** you have a unique index on the field.

Hence I am guessing there is an index of unique nature on col.key.